# How to limit Python regex 'greedyness' when asking for all chars before negative lookup

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have 4 matches with my pattern:

```
\d+\/?\d+\s[A-z]+.(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mPt19w/1)

[image: regex demo]

Require parsing of 4 strings:

```
17 Howard Rd Howard. Stdnt 
11/169 Wall Road, Wontown, Wkr 
105 AGNEW, Marilyn Barbara 
106 AGNEW, Mavis Rosina
```

If I add `*` or `+` after `.` The match goes to the end of the string. So I lose the matches and the negative lookup. How do I reconfigure this regex to extend the matches so I get 4 complete strings?

Comment: Use `+?` or `*?` and positive lookahead: [`\d+/?\d+\s[A-z]+.+?(?=\s\d|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/mPt19w/2)

Comment: ...or use `\D` (non-digit) if there is no digit in your road names: [`\d+/?\d+\s[A-z]+\D+`](https://regex101.com/r/mPt19w/3)

Comment: Thanks. I think my mistakes were (1) Contents of a positive lookahead are NOT part of a match (2) Adding the `?` to `.+`turns the 'unlimited times' `.+` lazy. Which then forces the returned matches to be 'restricted' by the positive lookahead.

Comment: Depending on data you might also consider to split: [`re.split(r' +(?=\d)', s)`](https://tio.run/##RY2xCsIwFEX3fMXd0mKpBrHiUERBdNGhDl1cIgkYrEl4CZZ@fYwguB3u4XD9FB/OLlMyL@8ogjRjAS24WOPkRkkKnfpRjWtUNkKIuWg26OUwoHNSVeidjW60GZ4EsVhhd7wc@gpnSWaYLPaS7pJkVs1fvU3IeTBWcsZIf19J18EPJhbEMSu27U2VvEIoGfNkbJ51KFP6AA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern matches at least 2 digits with this notation `\d+\/?\d+`
and note that `[A-z]` [matches more than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) `[A-Za-z]`

The dot in this part `.(?!\d)` also matches a space, that is why your matches have either a space or a comma at the end.

You might use:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:/\d+)?\s[A-Za-z].*?(?=\s+\d+\b|$)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\d+(?:/\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional `/` and 1+ digits
- `\s[A-Za-z].*?` Match a whitespace char followed by a single char A-Za-z and then as few as possible chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `\s+\d+\b` Match 1+ whitespace chars, 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of the string
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/duW5qA/1)